# How to form multipart sdp using sip servlets?

Tags: sip

I want to form a multipart SDP INVITE message using sip servlets.

Snapshot of the tcpdump showing example of multipart SDP shown below
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what part you need help with.   Do you know how to use the SIP Servlet API to create an INVITE?  If so, then you can add a body to the message like this:

```
SipServletRequest req;
// create the INVITE
req = ...

// create the SDP
Object multipartSDP = ...

req.setContent(multipartSDP, "multipart/mixed");
```

If you need some help creating the multipart SDP itself, then you can use the SDP utilities in the [JAIN-SIP distribution](http://jsip.java.net/).  Some example code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/jain-sip/source/browse/src/test/unit/gov/nist/javax/sip/multipartmime/MultipartMimeParserTest.java?r=205395d3be388d037ab5cdd0a5395367562b9006).